# Why does flexbox container split list items in two lines?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex element `<header>` which contains two flex items: `<span>` and `<ul>`

My goal is to display flex items horizontally in one line like in this photo:
[image]

but the result which I get is:
[image]
I have figured out that my problem may be solved by using `flex-basis: 100%;` But the behaviour of the flexbox container is not understandable for me.

Why does it split `<li>` items in two lines instead of displaying them in one?

**html:**

```
<header>
   <span>LOGO</span>
   <ul>
      <li>Library</li>
      <li>Telegram channel</li>
      <li>Contacts</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
   </ul>
</header>
```

**css:**

```
span {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
   padding: 10px;
}
li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 5%;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: You're applying flexbox to your header element so every children will be next to each other as expected. The ul splits in two lines because of the inline-block rule on your li element and it takes the available space of the ul, if you want it to be horizontal set a width: 100% in your ul

Comment: @JulianEspinosa but the default width of <ul> element is 100%. Why do we need to set it again?

Answer (score 0):

use `width:100%` and `margin:0` for `ul`

```css
span {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
   padding: 10px;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 5%;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <span>LOGO</span>
   <ul>
      <li>Library</li>
      <li>Telegram channel</li>
      <li>Contacts</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
   </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the solution. But my question is a bit different